# Partially replace dataframe with rows from another

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two similar dataframes, one has a single date and the other has multiple dates plus an additional column:

df:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id  | region | country  | product | count |
|------------|-----|--------|----------|---------|-------|
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | Spain    | P1      | 10    |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | England  | P1      | 9     |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | France   | P1      | 10    |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | Spain    | P2      | 299   |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | England  | P2      | 39    |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | France   | P2      | 10    |
| 2021-06-14 | 112 | LATAM  | Brazil   | P1      | 64    |
| 2021-06-14 | 112 | LATAM  | Paraguay | P2      | 21    |
| 2021-06-14 | ... | ...    | ...      | ...     | ...   |
```

df1:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id  | region | country  | product | count | fullfilments |
|------------|-----|--------|----------|---------|-------|--------------|
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | Spain    | P1      | 1     | 1            |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | England  | P1      | 1     | 3            |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | France   | P1      | 2     | 4            |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | Spain    | P2      | 1     | 1            |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | England  | P2      | 2     | 1            |
| 2021-06-14 | 111 | EMEA   | France   | P2      | 1     | 5            |
| 2021-06-14 | 112 | LATAM  | Brazil   | P1      | 2     | 2            |
| 2021-06-14 | 112 | LATAM  | Paraguay | P2      | 21    | 1            |
| 2021-06-14 | ... | ...    | ...      | ...     | ...   | ...          |
| 2021-06-13 | 111 | EMEA   | Spain    | P1      | 0     | 1            |
| 2021-06-13 | 111 | EMEA   | England  | P2      | 0     | 2            |
```

Df1 has many dates of grouped data and df only has one date. I would like to replace the `count` column in df1 with the `count` in df for matching rows (yyyy_mm_dd, id, region, country, product) and retain fullfilments.

I could probably join both together and drop count in the first df, however I only want to replace where the date is matching and retain all other rows in df1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `join` and use the `coalesce` function.

When you do the `left join` from the first dataframe to the second, the only matching records have the not null `new_count` value. Now, use the `coalesce` function that will return the first value when it is not null but the second value when the first is null.

```
coalesce(a   , b   ) => a
coalesce(a   , null) => a
coalesce(null, b   ) => b
```

From your dataframes,

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df1 = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").csv("test1.csv")

+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+
|yyyy_mm_dd|id |region|country |product|count|
+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P1     |10   |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |England |P1     |9    |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |France  |P1     |10   |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P2     |299  |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |England |P2     |39   |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |France  |P2     |10   |
|2021-06-14|112|LATAM |Brazil  |P1     |64   |
|2021-06-14|112|LATAM |Paraguay|P2     |21   |
+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+

df2 = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").csv("test2.csv")

+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
|yyyy_mm_dd|id |region|country |product|count|fullfilments|
+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P1     |1    |1           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |England |P1     |1    |3           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |France  |P1     |2    |4           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P2     |1    |1           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |England |P2     |2    |1           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |France  |P2     |1    |5           |
|2021-06-14|112|LATAM |Brazil  |P1     |2    |2           |
|2021-06-14|112|LATAM |Paraguay|P2     |21   |1           |
|2021-06-13|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P1     |0    |1           |
|2021-06-13|111|EMEA  |England |P2     |0    |2           |
+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
```

the join of two dataframes are given by follows:

```py
cols_to_join = ['yyyy_mm_dd', 'id', 'region', 'country', 'product']
df3 = df2.join(df1.withColumnRenamed('count', 'new_count'), cols_to_join, 'left') \
         .withColumn('count', f.coalesce('new_count', 'count')).drop('new_count')
df3.show(truncate=False)

+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
|yyyy_mm_dd|id |region|country |product|count|fullfilments|
+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P1     |10   |1           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |England |P1     |9    |3           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |France  |P1     |10   |4           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P2     |299  |1           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |England |P2     |39   |1           |
|2021-06-14|111|EMEA  |France  |P2     |10   |5           |
|2021-06-14|112|LATAM |Brazil  |P1     |64   |2           |
|2021-06-14|112|LATAM |Paraguay|P2     |21   |1           |
|2021-06-13|111|EMEA  |Spain   |P1     |0    |1           |
|2021-06-13|111|EMEA  |England |P2     |0    |2           |
+----------+---+------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: I arrived at a similar solution as well actually! Though my original question had a minor error. Is it also possible to also keep the count from `df1` when the dates match. I.e. I only want the `df2` count when `df2.yyyy_mm_dd` **<** `df1.yyyy_mm_dd`, otherwise `df1.count`. I was thinking to do `date_add(df1.yyyy_mm_dd,1)` prior to the join, it would work I think but a bit hacky

Comment: I made it work by using `.when()` along with `.otherwise()` based on the yyyy_mm_dd.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you need to retrieve a column from different dataframes you must join them:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df1.join(df.withColumnRenamed('count', 'new_count'),
               on=['yyyy_mm_dd', 'id', 'region', 'country', 'product'], how='left')

df2 = (df2
       .withColumn('count', f.coalesce('new_count', 'count'))
       .drop('new_count'))
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Won't this remove every date in df1 which isn't in df? I want to keep them and only replace the matching dates, 2021-06-14 from the sample.

Comment: I still think it is incorrect as you will drop count for all rows in df1 and after left joining, there will be only count for 2021-06-14. I.e. in the sample df1 final two rows will be missing. I want to keep all rows in df1 and replace count for matching date only.

Comment: Check it again.

Comment: I tried the latest solution and it errors that `count` is ambiguous because it is in both dataframes. It is specifically this part `.withColumn('count', f.coalesce('new_count', 'count'))`

Comment: Did you copy `df.withColumnRenamed('count', 'new_count')` specified inside `join`  function?